# Encrypt using jQuery and Decrypt using C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, security, encryption

I like to implement mechanisam where string on Cliend Browser encrypted using key before page post to server and then I can use server side C# code to decrypt that posted string using the same Key.

I am generating unique key on each page request using Random class.

### ASPX File

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtData" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="ClientKey" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="OnClick" OnClientClick="return EncryptData();"/>
```

### EncryptData()

```
function EncryptData() {
        var plaintext = $('#txtData').val();
        var secret = $('#ClientKey').val();
        var encrypted;// Encrypt(plaintext, secret);

        $('#txtData').val(encrypted);
        return true;
    }
```

### C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            int key = new Random().Next();
            ServerKey = key;
            ClientKey.Value = key.ToString();
        }
    }
protected void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Decrypt(txtData.Text, ServerKey.ToString()));
    }
```

### Update 1

I have seen same mechanisam on HDFC bank Login page where they first encrypt user's password and then post the form.

Comment: Having encrypting logic is not safe as it can be easily hacked and the decrypting logic can be easily guessed. Best way is to have the encrypting logic on the server side and use an Ajax call to call it from the browser.

Comment: @Ramki what if we encrypt using AES on Client and decrypt on server side. AES is good one.

Comment: @imlim, the problem is not the decryption itself. The problem is that you're trying to avoid a man-in-the-middle attack, but you're sending the keys to your client and thus is the encryption not worth anything.

Comment: Do your encryption and decryption logic in server side. Through javascript, it is easy for the beginner developer too to identify the logic.

Comment: @smoksnes Do you have any other Idea? I am trying to avoid post plain text password like other banking do.

Comment: Read this: [Javascript Cryptography Considered Harmful](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/). Also, jQuery is not an encryption library.

Answer (score 0):

I would reconsider the usage of what you are doing. You are encrypting something with a key, and then you send that thing to the server **together with the key**. Sure, it will be harder to read the value and it might frighten some low-level sniffers, but it isn't secure. It's [security by obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

Think of it like this. Alice wants to send a loveletter to Bob, but Alice don't want anyone else than Bob to read the loveletter so she puts it in a safe. Thinking that the loveletter is safe she mails it to Bob. But she remembers that Bob cannot open the safe, so in **the same package she also puts the key to the safe**.

The problem here is that the post office, or any other with access to the package, can open the safe. In this analogy Alice is the client (web browser, javascript), the internet wire is the post office and the server is Bob.

There are ways to encrypt it using javascript. Such as:

http://point-at-infinity.org/jsaes/

https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/

And if you still want to encrypt the data on client side, which there's no harm in doing, I would avoid sending the key in the request back to the server. It should be enough for the server to send it to the client. Then the client shouldn't have to send it back. Instead you can store in session on server side. This way you can at least make the man-in-the-middle-threat a little smaller.

But in this scenario I would use [https](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) for sending the data instead.

> The HTTPS uniform resource identifier (URI) scheme has identical
>   syntax to the standard HTTP scheme, aside from its scheme token.
>   However, HTTPS signals the browser to use an added encryption layer of
>   SSL/TLS to protect the traffic. SSL/TLS is especially suited for HTTP
>   since it can provide some protection even if only one side of the
>   communication is authenticated. This is the case with HTTP
>   transactions over the Internet, where typically only the server is
>   authenticated (by the client examining the server's certificate).

One may argue that https [can be cracked as well](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/03/16/has-https-finally-been-cracked/), but it's still a better choice for sending sensitive data.

Comment: I am agree with you for https, but I see on HDFC bank login page, they entrypt entered password and then they post it back to server. Even Penetration team suggest the same.

Comment: Indeed. There's no harm in encrypting the data on the client, as long as one is aware of it's limitations. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After some thought, here is what I propose you could do. Lets here from everyone else on what they think as well.

Create an additional key. a passphrase(probably a question and answer kind of thing, mothers name or pet name etc) and use that as the key for encrypting or decrypting.

So while logging the user will input

1. User Name
2. Password
3. A prerecorded question's answer which is stored on
   server side already during registration

On submit.

1. encrypt the password with answer to the prerecorded question.
2. when it is received in the server side decrypt the password with answer for the prerecorded question stored in server side(a database).
3. If the password matches allow or otherwise deny services.

This way anyone who intercepts your request to login to the server side will not have the key to decrypt. And as mentioned by smoksnes use https for additional security

Comment: With that said, father's name, mother's name or not secret questions... If it was me I will ask the user to enter their own question and answer that no one else knows.